# How to say network but not internet

Tags: translation

Could I use 网形成 to describe a "network" of things with arrows going between them, like this?
[image]

Does that sound right?

Dictionaries give 网络 for "network."  But it seems to me that today 网络 mostly means the internet so it is not a good word for this.  Am I wrong about that?

Another possiblity would be just 网.  But I am not sure how that would sound to people.

In fact this is for an article on mathematical category theory. Google search shows that when Chinese language websites on category theory use  网络 they normally do use it for the internet, and not to describe networks of arrows

Comment: there is another word 互联网 specially for Internet. when we talk about a thing like web, just 网, 网状 or 网形。your shape is just 网状图 (Shape => ,图,图形,形状, where the word shape is a noun, not verb, so 形状 not 形成)。“网状图” = a web-like shape.

Comment: Mathematically, it's a directed graph [有向图](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%9C%89%E5%90%91%E5%9B%BE) (or digraph, or oriented graph) or a weighted digraph 加权有向图.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Network" means 网状组织.

You can simply use only 网. For example,

television networks 电视网
a communications network 通讯网
a defense network 防卫网
an intelligence network 情报网
a network of railroads 铁路网
networks of arrows 箭头网; 箭号网

Comment: Neutral network: 神经元网络

Answer (score 1):

上面说的很对了，network就只是网。

网：1.用绳、线等结成的捕鱼捉鸟的器具：鱼～。～罗。～开一面（喻用宽大的态度来对待）。～漏吞舟（喻法令太宽，使坏人漏网）。
2.形状像网的东西：电～。发～。
3.像网一样的纵横交错的组织或系统：～点。通信～。天罗地～。
4.用网捕捉：～到一条大鱼。
5.像网似的笼罩着：眼睛里～着红丝。

网络：网络是由节点和连线构成，表示诸多对象及其相互联系

在书面特定语境下，网络代指internet

Answer (score 1):

A friend gave me the suggestion:树状图 but yours has more interconnections than a simple tree diagram, more like a 'bramble diagram'.

We suggest: 关键路径法

https://image.baidu.com/search/detailidlsimipic?tn=detailidlsimipic&dututype=similar&word=&pn=0&queryurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmt1.baidu.com%2Ftimg%3Fshitu%26quality%3D100%26sharpen%3D100%26er%3D%26imgtype%3D0%26wh_rate%3Dnull%26size%3D9%26sec%3D1491610492%26di%3D19c30d7c44ba2495bc15be71ece4d016%26cut_x%3D11%26cut_y%3D5%26cut_w%3D264%26cut_h%3D178%26src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fa.hiphotos.baidu.com%2Fimage%2Fpic%2Fitem%2F622762d0f703918ff050dd0f583d269758eec476.jpg&querysign=3880323461%2C4003492081&objwidth=611&objheight=215&objurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftimgsa.baidu.com%2Ftimg%3Fimage%26quality%3D80%26size%3Db10000_10000%26sec%3D1491610493%26di%3D2a1d0ce5fdf3386cfa7299e7a5efa8b1%26src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fimages.cnitblog.com%2Fblog%2F442008%2F201411%2F101627253979111.jpg&fromurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnblogs.com%2Fyangxia-test%2Fp%2F4087477.html&querytype=0